# Pay off Credit Card Debt now or later

Tags: banking, credit, debt, housing

I recently paid a non-refundable housing deposit of $1,300 for summer intern housing. The company I am going to work at this summer has outlined in my contract that I will receive $2,500 to cover living expenses that will be paid out June. I paid for the housing deposit using a credit card but can afford to completely pay it off using money in my checking account. Would it make sense to:

- Pay the card off in full (I have over 15,000 in checking currently)
- Pay the minimum monthly dues on the credit card and then pay the debt off once my housing assistance from the company is deposited into my checking account.
- Any other options or advice?

Comment: Could you clarify what the upside of minimum payments would be? Wouldn't that still incur interest? How much would that cost in interest until the company reimburses you?

Comment: Which one will cause you to have more money at the end?

Comment: What are your monthly expenses?

Comment: Generally speaking, if the options are to pay the credit card debt now or later, you should always pay for it now.

Comment: what do you gain by keeping that debt for so long?

Comment: Don't spend money you don't have yet. If you're paying something now assuming you'll get an amount in June, that's too far away to be relevant for the payment now.

Comment: Do you enjoy rhetorical questions?

Comment: Pay it off now. Never carry debt if you can avoid it. I can't imagine why you would put a charge that large on a credit card when you obviously have the cash to just write a check.

Comment: Does your card have interest, or are you in the middle of a 0% APR for X months period?

Answer (score 109):

You are conflating issues.

You made a charge on a credit card. You have the money, earning near-zero interest, but are wondering whether you should use that money to pay a (presumably) high interest debt.

Of course, the answer is pay now. Most of the details beyond that are not relevant.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP still have to pay of every monthly interest if he paid now ?

Comment: There is no interest charged if a card is paid in full every month.

Comment: Oh, so that an interesting difference in how it works between US and France.
Thx for this answer !

Comment: @Rolexel How do credit cards work in France? I live in Bulgaria and I am aware of at least 3 other EU states that are the same - no debt on CC, no interest to pay.

Comment: Digging the subject I learned that this behaviour also exists in France but I've seen credit cards working like short term loans. You agreed on an amount, could spend it as you wanted but you were paying back monthly, with fixed interest. You could pay it back at once but with every monthly interest you would've had to pay. Like a loan.

Comment: @Rolexel Interesting (no pun intended.) Thankfully, credit cards are not at all like that in the US. As long as you pay off the charges in full before the due date of the first statement on which they appear, there is no interest. Like many Americans (if not most,) I use credit cards for most of my expenses and have never paid interest on any of them.

Comment: @Rolexel: In the USA even personal loans compute the interest charges only on what is actually still owed.  Charging "the interest you would have owed" would be considered a kind of prepayment penalty and there can be clauses like that, but due to competition between lenders only those in the most desperate financial situations would be unable to avoid such terms.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica That depends on the charge, doesn't it?  I seem to recall reading that cash advances charge interest from day 0.  When I paid a deposit in Canada, I was told I could not use a credit card (because it's reversible), is it possible that a deposit payment is treated as a cash advance and incurs interest from day 0?

Comment: @gerrit - what you describe isn't a 'charge', it's a 'cash advance'.  Unless, you'd really like to say that you "charged a cash advance" but that's begging the question.

Comment: @gerrit, it is only a deposit from the point of view of the business. As a customer, when you pay for a deposit (like when renting a tool) it is usually the same as a regular purchase. There is another type of transaction, a pre-authorization, which is usually when an amount isn't already known, but the payment is expected to occur shortly after (very common when prepaying for gas at the pump). This is not a charge, it just blocks the funds on your card.

Comment: @gerrit, I think they may have refused the deposit from a credit card because the card could be stolen or you could always claim a chargeback and they lose both the car/tool/item and the money.

Comment: If OP has the money in a checking account with non-zero interest, but a zero interest credit card (promotion, etc), then there really isn't a reason to pay now either. I'm assuming OP is under the impression that there may be some benefit to having a balance on their credit card, especially given that OP sounds young

Comment: @Rolexel What card do you have in mind? / À quelle carte penses-tu ? Nearly all French credit cards do work like in other European countries. They also typically have much lower limits than US cards and people have fewer of them.

Comment: @Relaxed No specific card, I recall stores having credit cards services behaving more like loans than like what I've learned here bout credit cards

Comment: @Rolexel I am sure they do exist, typically through credit institutes like Cetelem, Sofinco or Cofinoga but that's not the general case. If you have a decent income, it's extremely common to get a credit card you pay in full every month without incurring any interest (*carte bancaire à débit différé*).

Answer (score 23):

If you have 15,000 in your checking account, you should see these two events (paying for house and getting money for internship) completely separated.

You pay your bill when it is due and no interest is charged (otherwise you'd pay more). Even if that leaves you with 10% less in your account, that's the cheapest way of doing it.

Answer (score 9):

> Pay the minimum monthly dues on the credit card and then pay the debt off once my housing assistance from the company is deposited into my checking account.

You're losing 2% (the inflation rate) on the checking account $15,000 , and **losing 18+%** APR on that $1500 CC balance every month you don't pay it off.

That's the guaranteed method of starting life in expensive, wasteful, unproductive debt.

The **only** fiscally prudent moves are:

1. Pay off the CC debt **now**.  No need to wait for the statement.  Just log in to the CC web site and pay the bill.
2. Move the unneeded portion of the remaining checking account balance into an online savings account so as to lose much less money to inflation.
3. Even better is to move some of *that* money into a 12 month CD or two so as to break even with inflation.

Comment: +1. But I'm curious, why the first advice? "Pay off the CC debt now. No need to wait for the statement". Isn't paying CC bills in full upon receipt enough?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica it's simpler that way IMO.  (If this had been 45 years ago when checking accounts paid a noticeable interest, my answer would have been different.)

Comment: I don't understand how that's simpler. Say over a month I buy 4 things. You suggest I logon to the CC website and pay each off immediately. Or I could pay the bill at the end of the month. Paying the whole thing once seems a lot easier than paying 4 times.

Comment: @SamDean I don't feel the "pain" of spending the money until it leaves my checking account, which means I don't feel the pain when it's charged on my credit card, even though I have a budget and track all my spending religiously. Paying my credit card when I spend the money keeps me from overspending. It's just a different preference/mode of operating.

Comment: This answer is worded far too strongly. The first point makes no difference whether you pay off now or after statement close, other than losing out on a slight bit of interest if you pay off sooner. The other two points are not universally true. My bank pays a _higher_ interest rate on your checking account than on CDs if you use direct deposit and your debit card each month, for example. These points aren't bad advice, but they're certainly not "the **only** fiscally prudent moves." Also, with $15k, honestly, I'd say putting part of that in real investments is _more_ fiscally prudent.

Comment: @SamDean I pay my card off each Sunday night.  I pay non-standard charges off almost immediately because I've found that improves cash flow management.

Comment: @gerrit I should clarify that.

Comment: @RonJohn Ah, thanks, that makes more sense.  More like 1.39% every month.

Comment: There is no (financial) benefit to paying your credit card bill before it's due.  In addition to being more work, there's also a real cost to it - by paying earlier than you need to, you're forgoing interest that that money could be earning (and if these are big purchases, that could be somewhat consequential).

Comment: @Jer "you're forgoing interest that that money could be earning".  As mentioned in a previous comment: if this had been 45 years ago when checking accounts paid a noticeable interest, my answer would have been different.

Comment: @RonJohn why does that money have to be stored in a checking account?  I keep my cash in a high(ish) yield savings account and make a transfer to my checking account once a month to ensure I have enough there to pay all the credit card bills.  To keep it simple I set the due date for all of the credit card bills to be the first of the month.

Comment: @Jer OP specifically said checking, but the idea of storing in savings and switching to checking after is a good suggestion for OP.

Comment: @Jer I also keep most of my money in an online savings account (though I only sweep the leftover money in at EOM).  Because of the six withdrawal per period limit, it takes some organization and forethought; I just find it easier and simpler to *not* run a "lean" checking account during the month.

Comment: @Jer also, online banks (Ally, at least) are only paying a 1.6% APY.  One month of $1,300 (mentioned by OP) at 1.6% is a whopping $1.73.  That's... **a rounding error** when you've got $15,000 in the bank.

Comment: Sure, it's not much, but 1) I still don't see any downside to paying the bills when they're due, and 2) keeping the money in a separate account would get one used to the process - later on in life when the CC bills are much higher, the process is already in place and the financial gains from it are more significant (at least on the order of "a few lattes a month"). re: the 6 withdrawal limit - I just have all my due dates set to the 1st of the month.  Then around the 23rd of each month I review what's due and transfer enough in to cover all of that (with some buffer).

Answer (score 2):

I always pay off my credit card (the full sum for that month) on the last day of 0% charges.

If you have the money to pay it off, it's wasteful to keep this debt and pay interest on it.

Comment: That's pretty risky, since many CC with 0% say that if you don't pay it off during the 0%, you end up owing all the back interest as if it had been accruing normally. If you miss that payment at the end, even by a day, you will end up paying more than expected. Since the OP has the money now, it's better to pay it off sooner than later, since paying it later is similar to gambling.

Comment: @computercarguy "gambling" - that's an exaggeration. It's not risky for me. I pay off my card on the same day every month.

Comment: Sure, when you are healthy and employed. But what happens if you lose your job or are in a car wreck? What about being on a vacation? There's any number of other reasons why people miss their normal payment days and why waiting to pay something like this is a risk. Not to mention being frivolous with purchase "because you have the money", only to end up not having it, which gets too many people into trouble. I should know, been there done that.

Comment: Kudos, Robert, for being in the minority who pays the card in full each month. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: Risky. Why not pay it off immediately ? Payment systems can sometimes delay payments

Comment: @vikingsteve My CC is in the same bank. Payment is instantaneous. But any ways, in Poland we have the [Elixir](https://www.kir.pl/en/banks/elixir/system-elixir/) interbank payments settlement service which (on standard days) guarantees 3 sessions per day. Depending on the bank a transfer in the morning is usually guaranteed to arrive same day or next. Don't You have these types of services?

Comment: Robert - Yes, if at the same bank, the transfer is same day. Different banks, I go to my checking acct, and the payment is made next day. People here are over-reacting to the potential for a missed payment.

Answer (score 1):

What's your concern to paying it off, that it will "confuse numbers" since money is bouncing around everywhere?  What's the amount of interest total you'll end up paying?  If you're comfortable paying that much interest, then it doesn't matter either way.  If you want to save the interest money, pay it off now.  Also having high percentages on credit cards harms your credit score short term (but once you pay it off it goes back to normal IIRC).  Unless your bank gives you some kind of bonus for maintaining a 15K balance...